# Python argparse error: the following arguments are required

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I have the following code:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance as dist
from imutils import perspective
from imutils import contours
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2

aparse = argparse.ArgumentParser()
aparse.add_argument("--image", type=float, required=True, help="image path")
aparse.add_argument("--width", type=float, required=True,  help="width of far left object (inches)")
args = vars(aparse.parse_args())
```

and I am getting the following error:

```
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] --image IMAGE --width WIDTH
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: the following arguments are required: --image, --width
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
SystemExit: 2
```

I tried to solve this problem but without any luck.
Can you please tell me why this error and how to resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: Is this in a `jupyter` notebook?  That's what I deduce from the `ipykernel_launcher`.  Have you tried to specify `image`and `width` in any way?

Comment: Try running this from OS shell with `python yourscript.py --image image_file --width 30`.  Do you really want to specify `type=float,` for a image path?  Or for a width (`int` might make more sense).

Comment: Tried in a google colab but same error there too

Comment: What have you tried?  We can't help you without seeing the command that invokes this script.  Do you even know what is meant by `command line` arguments?  What are the `image` and `width` values, and how are you trying to supply them?

Comment: @hpaulij Why you are are asking so many queries rather than helping directly to the problem ?

Comment: I showed you how in the second comment!